# Nested OR statements in Google Sheets - Match Evaluation Error

Tags: if-statement, indexing, google-sheets, match, nested-loops

Currently I'm trying to construct a nested OR statement in Google sheets if any number of items are true, but they return different values based on another IF statement. Right now an example of my code is:

IF(OR($AW2="email1@website.com", $AW2="email2@website.com", $BB2="email1@website.com", $BG2="email1@website.com", IF($BK3="X","Message1",IF($BK3="Y","Message2",IF($BK3="Z","Message3","")))),"")

Essentially I'm trying to say if email1 has signed off on a document in any cell, or if email2 has signed of on the document in AW2, then return the message code based on what is in BK3.

I've attached a sample sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14AiHNpWQcmIJIvPxqb4j2HHgNC8C1cF9YZOe5il14Ro/edit?usp=sharing

I keep getting a 'Did not find value in MATCH evaluation', even though the indexed emails are present.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(OR($AW2="email1@website.com",$AW2="email2@website.com",$BB2="email1@website.com",$BG2="email1@website.com"),IF($BK3="X","Message1",IF($BK3="Y","Message2",IF($BK3="Z","Message3",""))),"")
```

(Close the OR sooner.)